# Override setClass and setMethod in a package R 3.0.1

Tags: r, r-s4

I am having problem to override setClass  and setMethod in a package

Requirement: R 3.0.1, Rtools

Please find below the steps to recreate the problem:

## 1. Create class and method

```
setClass(Class="AAA",
           representation(
           name="character",
           val="numeric"
         )
)

setMethod("*", 
      signature(e1 = "numeric", e2 = "AAA"), 
      definition=function (e1, e2) {
          e2@val = e2@val * e1
      e2       
    }
)
```

## 2/ save the file in

> C:\AAA.r

## 3/  build a package

```
>  setwd("C:")
>  package.skeleton(name="AAA",code_files="C:\\AAA.r")
>  system("R CMD build AAA")
>  system("R CMD INSTALL --build AAA")
```

## 4/ testing

```
> library(AAA)
> x = new("AAA")
> x@val = 100
> -1 * x
An object of class "AAA"
Slot "name":
character(0)

Slot "val":
[1] -100

Slot "type":
character(0)
```

## 5/ override class and  method

```
setClass(Class="AAA",
           representation(
           name="character",
           val="numeric",
           type="character",
           desc="character"
         )
)

setMethod("*", 
     signature(e1 = "numeric", e2 = "AAA"), 
                  definition=function (e1, e2) {
                    if (e2@type == "double"){
                        e2@val = e2@val * (2 * e1)       
                    } else {
                        e2@val = e2@val * e1 
                    }
                                 e2
                  }
        )
```

## 6/ testing

```
> y = new("AAA")
> y@val=25
> y@type="double"
> -1 * y
Error in -1 * y : invalid object (non-function) used as method
```

Please advise

Comment: You forgot to return something from your new method. Did you mean to have `e2` as the last line?

Comment: yup, I fixed the example - but the error is still the same

Comment: setMethod("Arith", ... see ?Ops and ?callGeneric

Comment: if I use "Arith" method, would it be in one function for several operators(+", "-", "*", "^", "%%", "%/%", "/")?.

Comment: I would need only the "*" operators on the method

Comment: There is also an error if I specify the "where" parameter in setClass and setmethod part


`Error in assignClassDef(Class, classDef, where) : 
  class “AAA” has a locked definition in package ‘AAA’`

and

`Error in setMethod("*", where = "package:AAA", signature(e1 = "numeric",  : 
  the environment ‘AAA’ is locked; cannot assign methods for function ‘*’`